# Maximal bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty, statistics

Which question in MO has had maximal total bounties among other questions? I mean the total bounties which are given by the asker or other participants.

Comment: I think [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207845/the-sum-of-squared-logarithms-conjecture) is a good candidate -- the OP offered one ounce of fine gold for a correct answer. -- Of course this depends on the exchange rate between gold and MO points :-)

Comment: @StefanKohl, can any amount of fine gold ever be worth more than an MO point? :-)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta thank you for your revision of this question and also your answer to it.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, you are welcome. I'm glad if I could be of help. And I won't be offended if you want to undo or overwrite my edits.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta thanks for your kind message. of course your revision was very necessary, and your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If you are willing to trade ounces of gold for MO points, we may be able to come to an arrangement. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) is the perfect tool for this kind of questions.
The highest possible single bounty is 500 points.
(For details of bounties, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/help/bounty) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/set-bounties) help page.)
See the query [Questions that received a lot of bounty](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/298193/questions-that-received-a-lot-of-bounty).
It gives a list of questions that have received more than one bounty, sorted by total amount.
These exceed 500 points:

- [When does a modular form satisfy a differential equation with rational coefficients?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125688/55893), 1000 points (2 bounties)
- [The error in Petrovski and Landis' proof of the 16th Hilbert problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/171988/55893), 700 points (3 bounties)
- [Distributivity of group topologies on $\mathbb Z$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/180648/55893), 600 points (2 bounties)
- [Godel on recursion-theoretic hierarchies](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125596/55893), 550 points (2 bounties)